# jQuery iterate through HTML in a variable and remove first radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a some HTML stored in a javascript variable that looks like below. Example looks like below.

```
var divHTML = "<table><tbody><tr><td><input type='radio' name='radio_1'></td></tr><tr><td></td><tr><td><input type='radio' name='radio_2'></td></tr></tbody></table>;
```

I would like to iterate through the `divHTML` and remove the first radio button along with the `<tr></tr>` that wrapped around it and return the rest of the HTML. (could acheive the same by removing the first `<tr></tr>` as well I think - as it will remove what's inside but the end goal is to not see the first radio button).

Also created a JSFiddle with the string in place. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chin/ZDwTd/) Please help. Hope the question is clear and many thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be easier/acceptable to just use `$('#FormID [name=FirstRadio]').hide()`?

Comment: @CharlesSmith All radio buttons in a group have the same `name` attribute, so that would remove the entire group, not just the first button.

Comment: @CharlesSmith: Unfortunately my scenario is a bit complex than that. :-) So will have to figure out above.

Comment: is working with html in the string necessarily? if yes it goes more into text handling methods and regex in javascript. but if this only a way to fetch the elem this is not a good way to do this. especially not with jquery which is quite DOM oriented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a closing quote mark, by the way:

```
var divHTML = "<table><tbody><tr><td><input type='radio'></td></tr><tr><td></td><tr><td><input type='radio'></td></tr></tbody></table>";
var $divhtml = $(divHTML);
$divhtml.find(':radio:first').closest('tr').remove();

newHTML = $divhtml.clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html();
alert(newHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

don't know what you're doing but will this work?

```
var divHTML = "<table><tbody><tr><td><input type='radio'></td></tr><tr><td></td><tr><td><input type='radio'></td></tr></tbody></table>"

$('body').append($(divHTML));

$("input:first").hide();
```

or you can hide the first radio button in your divHTML "markup" *before* appending to the `<body>`...

```
var newHTML = $(divHTML);

$("input:first",newHTML).hide();

$('body').append(newHTML);
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JTUtf/)

Comment: Many Thanks. In my scenario @mblase75's solution is more suitable.